# How to create a Constructor with "input"?

Tags: jquery, function, constructor

I have four similar functions. And I will need to add even more in the future.

```
$inputFromAge.on("input", function () {
  var val = $(this).prop("value");
  if (val < min) { val = min; }
  else if (val > to) { val = to; }
  instance.update({ from: val });
});

$inputToAge.on("input", function () {
  var val = $(this).prop("value");
  if (val < from) { val = from; }
  else if (val > max) { val = max; }
  instance.update({ to: val });
});

$inputFromSalary.on("input", function () {
  var val = $(this).prop("value");
  if (val < min) { val = min; }
  else if (val > to) { val = to; }
  instance.update({ from: val });
});

$inputToSalary.on("input", function () {
  var val = $(this).prop("value");
  if (val < from) { val = from; }
  else if (val > max) { val = max; }
  instance.update({ to: val });
});
```

Is it possible to create a Constructor to make it simple?

`instance` is needed to Ion.RangeSlider works. [Full Code](http://live.datatables.net/sivelagi/4/edit) to clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for a contructor, just define a named function that you call from the event handlers.

```
function update_instance(el, to_or_from, min, max) {
  var val = $(el).val();
  if (val < min) { val = min; }
  else if (val > max) { val = max; }
  instance.update({ [to_or_from]: val });
}

$inputFromAge.on("input", function () {
  update_instance(this, 'from', min, to);
});

$inputToAge.on("input", function () {
  update_instance(this, 'to', from, max);
});

$inputFromSalary.on("input", function () {
  update_instance(this, 'from', min, to);
});

$inputToSalary.on("input", function () {
  update_instance(this, 'to', from, max);
});
```

Comment: It seems to be great, but applying to my code it returns me a lot of errors. Did you see that on live.datatables?

Comment: You never define the variables `min`, `from`, `to`, or `max`.